# JQuery Checkbox click event never returns true

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox

I can't seem to figure this out for something so simple. I am using jQuery 1.4.2 (though I tried later versions) in IE 11 and I can't seem to retrieve the checked value when the value should be true.

```
    <input id="<%=ID%>" class="abcdeCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="<%=ID%>" />
var cachedCheckedValues = new Array();
$('.abcdeCheckBox').bind('click', function()    
    {
        alert(this.checked);
        var indexCheck = cachedCheckedValues.indexOf(this.value);

        if(this.checked)
        {
            if(indexCheck == -1)
            {
                cachedCheckedValues.push(this.value);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cachedCheckedValues.splice(indexCheck, 1);
            alert("removing: " + this.value);
        }
    });
```

This never returns true and I can't understand why. It never adds the value to the array I have in the code.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable as an array. You can't use `.push()` on `null`.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Lxkd7qj1/

Comment: Have to tried refreshing your browser or clearing out your browser cache?

Comment: Can confirm, code does work. Whatever error you're having lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unusual problem. Not sure what could be causing it. I did find a workaround by re-selecting the element by its id and getting the checked value inside the click event. This code is using jQuery 1.4.2, old as it is, I don't think that's the difference. I ran the JSFiddle in the same browser and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code that you never declare the array before adding something to it. jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/t3f9xbu5/

```
//declare array 
var cachedCheckedValues = [];


$('.abcdeCheckBox').bind('click', function()    
    {


        alert(this.checked);

        var indexCheck = cachedCheckedValues.indexOf(this.value);

        if(this.checked)
        {
            if(indexCheck == -1)
            {
                cachedCheckedValues.push(this.value);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cachedCheckedValues.splice(indexCheck, 1);
            alert("removing: " + this.value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `cachedCheckedValues` needs to be defined outside the scope of the click, otherwise it will only just contain the latest value

Comment: well I just didn't show the declaration, but it does exist. Thanks.

Comment: How would this affect what `alert(this.checked)` shows?